# insert duplicate rows in csv

Tags: c#, sql, csv, duplicates

i want the c# code to insert duplicate row with some column value change in csv file.

i have a datatable with values as :

```
Number      Concept  Date      D/C  Customer    Amount
200227026   Test   19.05.2017   01  29009333    30.25
```

want this below as output :

```
Number      Concept  Date      D/C  Customer    Amount
200227026   Test   19.05.2017   01  29009333    30.25
200227026   Test   19.05.2017   50  704461      30.25
```

can anyone help ?
Thanks in advance

my current code :

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("Sr No");
dc.AutoIncrement = true;
dc.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
dc.AutoIncrementStep = 1;
dc.DataType = typeof(Int32);
table.Columns.Add(dc);
string a = null;
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();

using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("test", con))
using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
table.BeginLoadData();
da.Fill(table);
DataTableReader dtReader = new DataTableReader(table);
table.Load(dtReader);
table.EndLoadData();
}

sendreport(table, "", "test");
```

Comment: please paste your code

Comment: DataTable table = new DataTable();
                
using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("test", con))
using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{ cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 table.BeginLoadData();
da.Fill(table);
DataTableReader dtReader = new DataTableReader(table);
 table.Load(dtReader);
table.EndLoadData(); }         
sendreport(table, "", "test");

Comment: @Prajakta edit your post and put your code in there. And do you want to insert row with different value? or you mean you want to keep track the change log of that record?

Comment: @Lee i want to insert row with different values

Comment: @Prajakta any condition?? if none then why don't you just do 2 insert query.

Comment: @Lee Got it.. thank you :)